# Access name of file being written by fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js

I'm using fs.writeFile to write a number of files to a directory.  I'd like to use the name of the file being written in a callback (ex. printing "file x has been written").

How can I get the name of the file being written (x)?

Using the filename variable I passed to writeFile will not work due to writeFile being asynchronous.

Thanks!

Comment: The first parameter of fs.writeFile is the file name, as specified by you. Why can't you just console log that same string in the callback?

Comment: The callbacks for writeFile don't execute directly after writeFile is called because its asynchronous / non blocking.  This means writeFile will not return / execute its callback until the file has been written.  That takes a while, and since the variable in a for loop is constantly being overwritten, chances are it will be on a different iteration by the time write file is finished.  robertklep's answer below probably explains this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think you're doing something like this (just guessing, since you're not posting code):

```
var files = [ 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' ];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var filename = files[i];
  fs.writeFile(filename, CONTENTS, function(err) {
    console.log('File written:', filename);
  });
}
```

That's not going to work because `filename` will be reused and overwritten for each iteration.

The easiest solution would be to use `forEach`:

```
files.forEach(function(filename) {
  fs.writeFile(filename, CONTENTS, function(err) {
    console.log('File written:', filename);
  });
});
```

That will create a newly scoped `filename` variable for each iteration, which won't be overwritten.